# mailbox.item.body.getAsync() with correction type 'Html' returns symbols

Tags: outlook, add-in, outlook-web-addins

When using `mailbox.item.body.getAsync()`  with correction type 'Html' it works properly on all web environments, but unfortunately  in Office Outlook 2016 desktop app it returns unknown symbols , if I changing correction type to 'Text' it returns normal text

[image]

Comment: I don't reproduce this, so it may be that you need a specific type of message, or it may be that I have a different version that's fixed this. What version number do you show in File->Office Account?

Comment: 16.0.6001.1073, this symbols are returned for all messages

Comment: Ok, I'm on a later build, 16.0.6916.1000. Can you check for updates and see if you still have the issue?

Comment: Its says that there is no update ( I've tried it before

Comment: Hmm, well that looks like a known problem that we fixed in a later build, and they are definitely released. You might want to try Windows Update (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Update-Office-and-your-computer-with-Microsoft-Update-2ab296f3-7f03-43a2-8e50-46de917611c5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue that we fixed where the viewer was returning the body in UTF-16, but the API is expecting the data in UTF-8. Those "unknown symbols" are the [UTF-16 BOM marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Updating Office should fix the issue.

Comment: thank you for your response, the thing is that , we are unable to update version, how can we do that ? when we trying to update manually  it says "There is no updates"

Comment: Are you on Office 365? Try going to "FILE", then "Office Account" and click on "Updates". Does it say to enable automatic updates?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a bug that has been fixed in the following:

- Outlook 2013 - 15.0.4772.1000 and later
- Outlook 2016 C2R - 16.0.6230.1000 and later

It has not been fixed in Outlook 2016 MSI. The fix for this is coming soon.

To check if you are MSI or C2R see this link: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114689#bookmark-officeinstall

(note that the fix listed in the link does NOT fix the issue, I just used it as a reference for C2R vs MSI)